# Django forms: rendering different data in forms per users login

Tags: python, django

Hello i'm currently making a webiste in Django, is it possible to render different select fields by querying the objects atributed in user via `request.user.id` to obtain and get the datas inputted by the user instead of all data gathered on all users? thank you so much

```
class clientforms(forms.Form):
  projectfield = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= Project.objects.all(),
    widget=forms.Select(attrs={
        'class' : 'form-control',
    })
    )
```

Comment: I think you can override the `__init__` method of form, there you will get request and then you can assign `self.projectfield.choices=your_filter` and you have access to self.request.user .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

credits to original answer :
[Django forms: rendering different data in forms per users login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74066985/django-forms-rendering-different-data-in-forms-per-users-login?noredirect=1#comment130773388_74066985)

based on the previous answer on the link you must override the original forms

forms.py

```
class clientforms(forms.Form):
 projectfield = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= Project.objects.all().filter(profile=1),
    widget=forms.Select(attrs={
        'class' : 'form-control',
    })
    )
    #add the overriding function
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(clientforms, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['projectfield'].queryset=Project.objects.all().filter(profile=Profile.objects.get(user_id=user.id))
```

on your views.py

```
# add the request.user on your forms
user = request.form
form = clientforms(user)
```